# MySQL server installation on Linux

Tags: linux, mysql

Am installing mysql. Having gotten to the point of: testing the linked copy of the startup script in the normal server runlevel start directory, to make sure the symlink was properly set up:

This is the error i get -bash: /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S90mysql: No such file or directory

And starting the mysql failed.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to startup scripts, it's very specific to your linux distribution. What is your distribution ?

Have you tried to install mysql-server via your package manager ? It should take care of this script by itself.